# How to animate line-drawing in iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, core-animation

I have been searching around, but there seems no good answer for this simple question. So I am asking again: how to animate line-drawing in iphone dev?

Basically what I want is something like this:

```
@implementation MyUIView

- (void) triggerLineDrawing: (CGPathRef) path {
   ...
   // animate line drawing here
   // and the line should disappear automatically after a few seconds
}
```

Can it be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "animate"? Appear pixel-by-pixel? Or simply appear by changing opacity from fully transparent to opaque?

Comment: yes, something like pixel-by-pixel. Not fade-in and out.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? I'm looking to do the same thing, and the timer solution is lagging my app something shocking. There has to be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it automatically, only bu hand. To do it manually you should do something like this:

- create array of your line points.
- start an NSTimer, that will fire for example, 15 times a second.
- every tick of a timer you have to find out, what part of the line you need to draw (look at linear interpolation)
- update path that you draw (only with needed points + one last point that moves)
- send setNeedsDraw message to view.

You can vary interpolation algorythm, speed of line drawing etc. to get the effect that you need.